# How to parse a structured text file into MySQL records using Python

Tags: python

In my Ubuntu repo server, I have a file named Packages.
This file is highly structured, with distinct sections separated by a blank line.
Here is an example of one entire section, with a blank line separator, and a beginning of the next section:

```
Package: account-plugin-aim
Priority: optional
Section: gnome
Installed-Size: 941
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Telepathy maintainers <pkg-telepathy-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Source: empathy
Version: 3.8.6-0ubuntu9
Replaces: account-plugin-empathy
Depends: empathy (= 3.8.6-0ubuntu9), telepathy-haze, mcp-account-manager-uoa, unity-asset-pool (>> 0.8.24daily13
.03.20.1)
Breaks: account-plugin-empathy
Filename: pool/main/e/empathy/account-plugin-aim_3.8.6-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb
Size: 8838
MD5sum: f7f709442600bb60bc5e230f905773ae
SHA1: 588d6aa693e4b9a9bda228360bc65dfab4527ed8
SHA256: 4a34e416bb37191d0b8e6855b27cdbf7cd63fec182ab415cc9e71b19cfe55e48
Description: Messaging account plugin for AIM
Homepage: http://wiki.gnome.org/Empathy
Description-md5: 1a2069e5dd5f4777061642b2d7c9a76a
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 5y
Task: ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-usb, edubuntu-desktop, edubuntu-usb

Package: account-plugin-facebook
```

I would like to use Python to help me create MySQL database record from each such section.
I'm looking for a syntax to read a single section into a python dictionary, before I turn that dictionary into a MySQL data row

Comment: Python could do that yes. You'd need to write some code of course, but once you have that It'll be easy.

Comment: I haven't used it personally, but- recognizing that ubuntu is a flavor of debian- you might be able to reuse a prebuilt parser for debian package files. Eg https://packages.debian.org/sid/python-debian / https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-debian

Comment: this looks promising and specific to my end-goal. will have a close look in the morning. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode

```
let 'out' be an empty list
append an empty dict to 'out'

for each line in file
   if line is blank
      append an empty dict to 'out'
   otherwise
      split line into key and value
      add key,val to last element of 'out'
```

This creates a list of dicts in `out`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simple way to do it:

1. Split your content on `\n\n` (two blank lines)
2. Next, split each section on `:` with a regular expression.
3. Zip up the results of #2 to form a dictionary.
4. Insert into a parameterized query.
5. Commit transaction
6. Rinse, Lather, Repeat.